# how send variable in other form is this code is correct?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

```
$("#delete").click(function() {
    deleterecord();
});

function deleterecord(){
    var id = $("#iduser").val();
    alert("aw"+id);
    var id     = $('#iduser').attr();   
    e.preventDefault();
    pressed = "delete"  

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "IngSave.php",
        data: "&idshit="+ id,
        data: "&gagawin="+ pressed,
        success: function(){
            alert("ATTENTION");
            $("#usertbl").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I'm not getting the variables  `$_POST['idshit'];` and  `$_POST['gagawin'];` in `IngSave.php` file.

Comment: Where does the variable come from?

Comment: you cant use `data: ..`  twice. and please don't use swear words in your examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "IngSave.php",
    data: {idshit:id,gagawin:pressed},
    success: function(){
        alert("bitch");
        $("#usertbl").html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two `data` params incorrectly in your `ajax` call, change it to

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "IngSave.php",
    data: "idshit="+id+"&gagawin="+pressed, // or - { idshit:id,gagawin:pressed }
    success: function(){
        alert("bitch");
        $("#usertbl").html(data);
    }
});
```